# How can I set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable in R?

Tags: r

When I execute the following code on R:

```
plot(x,fx(x),type="l",main="Probability Density Function of 
X~uniform(-1,1)",xlab="x",ylab="f(x) (pdf of X)")
```

I get the following red-warning message on the screen, although the plot is successfully showing:

```
TEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. ktrace, please set     
CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

How can I set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable on R? I have seen several questions here that applies to XCode, but there seem to be no similar question for R.

Thank you,

Comment: Can't reproduce the warning, probably OS related. Please edit your post with `sessionInfo()`.